# Completely disabling Chrome browsing history

Tags: google-chrome, history

I disabled browsing history from My Activity and deleted all elements; I made Chrome's History file read only; my browsing history from Clear browsing data shows "None" and I disabled history sync. Despite this, history is still saved: if I do a search, then that same search shows in my history (with a clock icon) when I type in the address bar, also if I close Chrome.

If I do Clear browsing data history doesn't appear anymore, but since history was marked as "None" something seems wrong.

How can I completely disable Chrome's history? Using incognito sessions wouldn't work, since that doesn't store logins, either.

System: Chrome 78.0.3904.97, Windows 10 1903 18362.418.

Comment: Did chrome make a new History file?

Comment: No, I have just one History file, which is read only and doesn't contain any addresses from history.

Comment: You need to specify the Chrome version and your OS.

Comment: Sorry, I completely overlooked that info; I'll edit the question: Chrome 78.0.3904.97, Windows 10 1903 18362.418.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last openend link are saved in the user profile directory, `Shortcuts` file; by resetting it and making it read only, when I open Chrome all the previously opened links are gone.

Answer (score 1):

*Firstly*, consider **switching to Firefox, which allows you to turn off browsing
history in its settings** and has more concern for privacy overall.

*Secondly*, if you still prefer to use Chrome, you may want to **configure your
Chrome shortcuts to start the browser in incognito mode**, because in this mode
Chrome will not record your history. On Windows you can do the following.

1. **Navigate to the location** of the shortcut:

   - Go to `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop`
     to find your **desktop** shortcut;
   - Go to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
     to find the **start menu** shortcut;
   - Go to `%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`
     to find your **taskbar** shortcut;
   - Go to wherever you stash your browser shortcuts,
     if none of the above applies. **:)**
2. **Change the properties** of the shortcut:

   - **Open** the properties and go to the `Shortcut` tab;
   - **Edit** the `Target` property: append  `-incognito` to the end of the value,
     for example, in **my case** the value would look like as follows:
     `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -incognito`;
   - Hit `OK` to **save and close** the properties.
3. **Test** the shortcut:

   - **Open** Chrome by using your modified shortcut;
   - The **profile button** in the top right of Chrome should say `Incognito`.

*Bonus*: If you start Chrome with a **text command** rather than a shortcut,
just append  `-incognito` to the end of the command to start it in incognito mode:

- For example, `Win + R`; `chrome -incognito`; `Enter`.

Please note that **this does NOT entirely prevent Chrome from working in normal
mode**, in which it does record your history, so be careful when you open new
windows, for example:

- Use the `New incognito window` option instead of `New window`;
- Use the hotkey `Ctrl + Shift + N` to create a new **incognito** window,
  rather than `Ctrl + N` which would create a **normal** window.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome, therefore Google keeps your history in their databases as well, you need to go to your google account. Find, "Manage your activity", then privacy, there you should see Web & App Activity and then you can disable it.

Comment: I did, in my "Web & App Activity" I have "Web & App Activity (paused)" and I have "Include Chrome history and activity from sites, apps, and devices that use Google services" unchecked. There is something else to do?

Comment: @Mauro How about in Chrome settings, Sync and Google Services tab, what does it look like?

Comment: In Settings I have History sync disabled; I'm not sure what do you mean by Google Services tab. Anyway I think I found the culprit, I'll post about it shortly.

Comment: There is a section called Sync & Google Services in Chrome settings. It says what to save. But I'm glad you figured out.

Comment: I think I disabled all that can be disabled there - it just seems `Shortcuts` can't be disabled from there (or I'm totally missing something). Thanks for the suggestion, though.